# Method call resolves as function call on a class

Tags: python, python-2.7, methods, twisted

I have python2.7 and twistd framework. I am using [twisted-theseus](https://github.com/flowroute/twisted-theseus)==0.14.1.3 library.

I have following as first two lines in my twistd plugin:

```
from theseus import Tracer

t = Tracer()
t.install()
```

I fail with exception:

> exceptions.TypeError: install() takes exactly one argument (0 given)

What is wrong here? Looks like it was called install() not on the object receiver but on the class.

Comment: For me, that snippet won't give any error on a python 2.7 virtualenv but I'll get the same error on a python3.6.x virtualenv, I'm puzzled

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This appears to be due to a known issue with twisted-theseus: https://github.com/habnabit/twisted-theseus/issues/1.

There is a workaround on the Github issue:

```
$ pip install cython
$ git clone https://github.com/habnabit/twisted-theseus
$ cd twisted-theseus
$ pip install .
```

Comment: So the PyPI package isn't usable since 2016 and the author knows. Wow.